# Why does LET not play nice with EVAL in my quine?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, eval, quine

I was trying to write a Common Lisp quine.  I figured one of the simplest options was as follows:

```
(let ((program '`(let ((program ',program )
                   (print (eval program)))))
  (print (eval program))))
```

This does not work, SBCL and CLISP both complain that PROGRAM is unbound.  I did, however, find that using DEFPARAMETER, unlike LET, *does* work:

```
(progn
  (defparameter program
                '`(progn
                    (defparameter program
                                  ',program)
                    (print (eval program))))
  (print (eval program)))
```

For the second example the only difference between the code printed and the code written is the whitespace and capitalization, which I can easily fix.  I still, however, do not understand why my first attempt was not working.   As I see it, the only difference is the scoping of the variable, but it really seems like it shouldn't matter since I'm evaluating program within the scope that contains it.

Comment: Quines are easy with reader variables, but maybe this is considered cheating. Maybe try with anonymous functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(let ((program '`(let ((program ',program )
                   (print (eval program)))))
  (print (eval program))))
```

The Common Lisp standard says about `eval`:

> Evaluates *form* in the current *dynamic environment* and the null *lexical environment*.

Since `program` is a lexical variable, it's not visible to `eval`.

Comment: Note that you can work around this in a slightly horrible way by adding suitable `(declare (special program))` declarations as the first thing in the two binding forms.